# What does Average Engagement Time in Google Firebase mean?

Tags: session, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I am trying to interpret what Average User Engagement Time in Google Firebase means? Is it the same as Average Session Duration in GA?

I have a web app as well as mobile app.
Since I am using google analytics for the web app, I can get the Avg. Session Duration for the web app there. On the other hand, I use google firebase for the mobile app.

Can I compare the average user engagement time (mobile app) with average session duration (web app) to compare effectiveness of both versions of the apps?

Any help would be appreciated!